# Which dispatch.fcgi provides the same behaviour as "rackup"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, rack, fastcgi

I have a ruby rack application that I would like to manage behind FCGI.

What should I put inside the `dispatch.fcgi` file so the executed application matches/uses the content of config.ru ?

I would like the application launched by fcgi to be identical to the one launched when running `rackup`.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: There's good reasons why people don't use FCGI these days. Try finding a host that supports Apache / Nginx.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg, what are those reasons?

Comment: @avakar: It's old and it's exceptionally difficult to set up. THere are simply better alternatives out there.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the following at the bottom of a dispatch.fcgi script to start a fastCGI server based on a config.ru just like rackup would:

```
Rack::Server.start(
                   :config => 'config.ru',
                   :server => 'fastcgi'
                   )
```